# mpv not using embedded fonts for subtitles

Tags: linux-mint, fontconfig, mpv

[image: How it is supposed to look]
How it is supposed to look.

[image: How it looks]
How it looks.

I can see in mpv's log that it does call for Murga, the right font embedded in the mkv file, but it ends up falling back to BitstreamVeraSans-Roman.

```
[sub/ass] fontselect: (Murga, 400, 0) -> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/emoji/TwitterColorEmoji-SVGinOT.ttf, 0, TwitterColorEmojiSVGinOT
[sub/ass] Glyph 0x45 not found, selecting one more font for (Murga, 400, 0)
[sub/ass] fontselect: (Murga, 400, 0) -> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf, 0, BitstreamVeraSans-Roman
```

Deleting `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` seems to fix the issue, but I wonder if there's some kind of rule I could add to it to fix the issue.
Here's the content of my fonts.conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<!-- /etc/fonts/fonts.conf file to configure system font access -->
<fontconfig>

<!--
    DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
    IT WILL BE REPLACED WHEN FONTCONFIG IS UPDATED.
    LOCAL CHANGES BELONG IN 'local.conf'.

    The intent of this standard configuration file is to be adequate for
    most environments.  If you have a reasonably normal environment and
    have found problems with this configuration, they are probably
    things that others will also want fixed.  Please submit any
    problems to the fontconfig bugzilla system located at fontconfig.org

    Note that the normal 'make install' procedure for fontconfig is to
    replace any existing fonts.conf file with the new version.  Place
    any local customizations in local.conf which this file references.

    Keith Packard
-->

<!-- Font directory list -->

    <dir>/usr/share/fonts</dir>
    <dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>
    <dir prefix="xdg">fonts</dir>
    <!-- the following element will be removed in the future -->
    <dir>~/.fonts</dir>

<!--
  Accept deprecated 'mono' alias, replacing it with 'monospace'
-->
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>mono</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same">
            <string>monospace</string>
        </edit>
    </match>

<!--
  Accept alternate 'sans serif' spelling, replacing it with 'sans-serif'
-->
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>sans serif</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same">
            <string>sans-serif</string>
        </edit>
    </match>

<!--
  Accept deprecated 'sans' alias, replacing it with 'sans-serif'
-->
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>sans</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same">
            <string>sans-serif</string>
        </edit>
    </match>

<!--
  Ignore dpkg temporary files created in fonts directories
-->
    <selectfont>
        <rejectfont>
            <glob>*.dpkg-tmp</glob>
        </rejectfont>
    </selectfont>
    <selectfont>
        <rejectfont>
            <glob>*.dpkg-new</glob>
        </rejectfont>
    </selectfont>

<!--
  Load local system customization file
-->
    <include ignore_missing="yes">conf.d</include>

<!-- Font cache directory list -->

    <cachedir>/var/cache/fontconfig</cachedir>
    <cachedir prefix="xdg">fontconfig</cachedir>
    <!-- the following element will be removed in the future -->
    <cachedir>~/.fontconfig</cachedir>

    <config>
<!--
  Rescan configuration every 30 seconds when FcFontSetList is called
 -->
        <rescan>
            <int>30</int>
        </rescan>
    </config>

</fontconfig>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font, specifically the following block from the file `$HOME/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/56-twemoji-color.conf`:

```xml
  <match target="pattern">
    <!-- If the requested font is sans-serif -->
    <test qual="any" name="family">
        <string>sans-serif</string>
    </test>
    <!-- Make Bitstream Vera Sans the first result -->
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend_first">
      <string>Bitstream Vera Sans</string>
    </edit>
    <!-- Followed by Twitter Color Emoji -->
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend_first">
      <string>Twitter Color Emoji</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
```

The same block is present in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/56-twemoji-color.conf`.